# Is spatial-interpolation a synonym for interpolation?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[spatial-interpolation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-interpolation) (21 questions):

> spatial interpolation is the procedure of estimating the value of properties at unsampled sites within the area covered by existing observations

[interpolation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpolation) (228 questions):

> The estimation of values at unsampled points based on known values of surrounding points.

<sub>I'd, you know, use the built-in feature for suggesting tag wiki synonyms, but you need 2500 reputation to do that.</sub>

Comment: 6 for and 0 against makes this clearcut so I merged [tag:spatial-interpolation] into [tag:interpolation] making the latter the master.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think [spatial-interpolation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-interpolation) should be made a synonym of [interpolation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpolation).

Clearly, spatial interpolation is a subset of interpolation, but in the context of a site about GIS, there is little value in trying to tease the two apart.

The [interpolation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpolation) tag is already used as a de facto master synonym, so let's just make it official.